# xamarin android customtabs NavigationEvent won't call

Tags: xamarin.android, android-customtabs

I'm using android.suport.customtabs in xamarin to show webpages,
i can't get NavigationEvent to be called, when pages are done loading.

i followed the sample from here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/blob/master/customtabs/samples/ChromeCustomTabsSample/MainActivity.cs

But can't get it to work.
It opens the page, and i can customize it, but NavigationEvent never gets called, what are the sample missing??

please any info would be a big help.

Comment: what exactly you need to do ?? give sample of your code and where the issue